# lein repl without network connection

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

Can I open a lein repl connection,
or cider-jack-in in Emacs,
without a network connection?
The computer which needs lein repl is behind some network that blocks some IPs so that it cannot connect to the (lein?) server and cannot use a vpn to bypass this problem either.
So is there a way to start lein repl without network connection?
Thanks

Comment: cider-jack-in doesn't use a network connection. Isn't completely local. What errors are you getting?

Comment: lein it's self will try to connect to the internet to update dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell lein not to try to do things requiring an internet connection with the `-o` flag:

```
lein -o repl
```

You need to, of course, make sure the dependencies are available before you do this. And you should most definatly **always run your production stuff in this mode** if you run it from lein, because fetching dependencies as your service starts in production is crazy (and I've been burned by this twice too many times)

Lein will, by default, try to go online to do things like checking for new snapshot dependencies (you should not use these).

Comment: Thanks. And can i add -o to cider jack in?

Comment: I don't know, you can start the repl in a terminal and then run M-x `cider-connect` to connect to the repl you started.